# opencv "vector iterators incompatible"

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, opencv

I am using opencv 2.2 and VC++(2008) to track an object, while  using goodFeaturesToTrack in the program '*vector iterators incompatible*' error occurs

```
vector<Point2f> points;
goodFeaturesToTrack(mat,points,10, 0.01, 10, Mat(), 3, 0, 0.04);
```

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead.

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;
cv::Mat pointmat(points);
cv::Mat tempmat = Mat(mat.rows,mat.cols, cv::CV_32FC1);
goodFeaturesToTrack(mat,pointmat, tempmat,10, 0.01, 10, Mat(), 3, 0, 0.04);
```

goodFeaturesToTrack takes an additional argument of tempimage as per the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_feature_detection.html). Its first 3 arguments are of type CvArr, which a `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` isn't , hence difference in `std::vector` iterators error message.